# Андроид Студио. Как программно (в коде) перезагрузить (перезапустить) приложение?

Tags: android, android-studio

Такая необходимость возникает, например, при смене языка, изменении размера шрифтов и т.д.

Я понимаю, что при смене языка советуют перезагружать все активити (внутри приложения) и т.д.
Но охота узнать как вообще перезапустить приложение. )
Потому что это еще и очень интересно! )

Comment: System.exit(0) попробуйте. Но вообще это некрасиво, лучше влёт делать.

Comment: Спасибо. Но это же только exit. А run как сделать?

Comment: это андроид) тут всё немного по-другому. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292016/difference-between-finish-and-system-exit0

Comment: @YuriK никак, да и незачем. При смене конфигурации происходит автоматическое пересоздание всех активити в вашем приложении, за это отвечает операционная система. Все, что вы перечислили - относится к смене конфигурации.

Comment: Спасибо, Mit! А как сменить конфигурацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

Здесь mStartActivity - это активити, которая будет запущена после выхода из приложения.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17166729/8513267

Comment: Спасибо! Этот вариант решения работает, но только если System.exit(0) заменяю на finish()

Comment: @Yuri K а вот статья по смене конфигурации https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html